# Capturing full screen screenshot using C# Selenium WebDriver html2canvas returns null

Tags: c#, selenium, html2canvas

I have problem getting output from html2canvas JS library within Chrome automated by selenium.
Response is always null, but I can see in the Chrome console that code executed successfully and screenshot has been encoded

```
public byte[] TakeScreenshot(string fileName)
    {
        this.logger.Debug($"Taking screenshot");
        var seleniumDownloadPath = this.seleniumEngine.GetDownloadPath();
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        var html2canvasJs = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath), this.seleniumEngine.GetHtml2CanvasPath()));
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        var response = new object { };

        js.ExecuteScript(html2canvasJs);

        string generateScreenshotJS =
             var canvasImgContentDecoded;
             @"function genScreenshot () {
             html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
             window.canvasImgContentDecoded = canvas.toDataURL(""image/png"");
             console.log(window.canvasImgContentDecoded);
             return window.canvasImgContentDecoded;
             });
             }
             genScreenshot();";

        response = js.ExecuteScript(generateScreenshotJS);
}
```

[image]

I also tried solution from this [Here](https://www.automatetheplanet.com/full-page-screenshots-webdriver-html2canvas/) but the behavior was unstable (e.g. when running realtime i got error of nulls, but if running using breakpoints, I got result sometime)

Comment: i dont know if this help but in java we use Ashot library

Comment: @Yan thanks but I already got output from html2canvas, so I would like to use this but I am missing something which will return result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution after finding out that execution of script takes more time and variable was null. So added wait function to retrieve once its filled - window.canvasImgContentDecoded

```
public byte[] TakeScreenshot(string fileName)
    {
        this.logger.Debug($"Taking screenshot");
        var seleniumDownloadPath = this.seleniumEngine.GetDownloadPath();
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = Driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        var html2canvasJs = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath), this.seleniumEngine.GetHtml2CanvasPath()));
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
        var response = new object { };

        js.ExecuteScript(html2canvasJs);

        string generateScreenshotJS =
             @"
             var canvasImgContentDecoded;
             function genScreenshot () {
             html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
             window.canvasImgContentDecoded = canvas.toDataURL(""image/png"");
             console.log(window.canvasImgContentDecoded);
             });
             }
             genScreenshot();";

        response = js.ExecuteScript(generateScreenshotJS);

        string getSCreenShot = "return window.canvasImgContentDecoded;";

        var encodedPngContent = new object { };
        
        /*ADDED WAIT FUNCTION*/
        wait.Until(
        wd =>
        {
            encodedPngContent = js.ExecuteScript(getSCreenShot);
            if (encodedPngContent != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });

        string pngContent = encodedPngContent.ToString();
        pngContent = pngContent.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", string.Empty);
        string fileSavePath = this.seleniumEngine.GetDownloadPath() + fileName;
        File.WriteAllBytes(fileSavePath, Convert.FromBase64String(pngContent));
        byte[] fileByte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileSavePath);
        File.Delete(fileSavePath);
        return fileByte;
    }
```